# phpmyadmin 4.8.5 export page is blank

Tags: phpmyadmin

start phpmyadmin, click on Export tab, displays blank page. would prefer working export page.

Database Server version: 5.5.59-log
PHP version: 5.6.40
phpMyAdmin: Version 4.8.5

does not matter where you start, clicking the export tab displays a blank page.

tried lots of solutions online, none worked, most did not apply to version 4.8.5.

no javascript / jquery errors, no php errors, no server errors

The 4.8.5 is a clean installation in a new folder. updating from 4.7.2 which ran without problems. used same config.inc.php file.

Comment: Same problem with 5.2.0